# Firestore database time-series data modelling

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to store time-series data in firestore database in a way that would allow to retrieve and update it as efficiently as possible by utilizing firebase filtering capabilities and best practices.

In terms of actual data that will be stored is daily data points that will have a corresponding single numeric value, e.g. 1580651062 - 45.

The following is an example of the initial firestore structure that needs to be followed:

***/exampleData/userId/accountId/*** <-- and from here on I would like to store time-series data.

Example json structure:

```
"exampleData": {
    "123": { // accountId
        "1546300800": { // 'yearKey' - 2019/01/01/00:00:000
            "1548979200": [ // 'monthKey' - 2019/02/01/00:00:000, that contains daily data of 2019/02/x/xx:xx:xxx
                {
                    "timestamp": 1549070411,
                    "value": 20
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": 1549077675,
                    "value": 10
                }
            ],
            "1551398400": [ // 'monthKey' - 2019/03/01/00:00:000, that contains daily data of 2019/03/x/xx:xx:xxx
                {
                    "timestamp": 1551669675,
                    "value": 22
                }
            ]
        },
        "1577836800": { // 'yearKey' - 2020/01/01/00:00:000
            "1577836800": [ // 'monthKey' - 2019/02/01/00:00:000, that contains daily data of 2019/02/x/xx:xx:xxx
                {
                    "timestamp": 1580651062,
                    "value": 33
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the above I have the following as a potential solution:

```
/exampleData
    /userId(Document) 
        /797499614(Collection)
            /randomDocId
                /yearlyData(Collection)
                    /randomDocId
                        /monthlyData(Collection)
                            /randomDocId
                                /dailyData(Collection)
                                    /randomDocId
```

where yearlyData collection contain yearKey's and corresponding monthlyData collections which then contain monthKey's and corresponding dailyData collection that contains separate document for each data point within which dayKey and a value. In theory, having the latter structure should allow to perform granular filtering and allow to minimize the amount of data is downloaded to the client before processing, e.g.

```
db.collection("exampleData")
  .doc("userId")
  .collection("accountId")
  .collection("yearlyData")
  .where("yearKey", ">=", 30)
  .where("yearKey", "<=", 40)
  .getMonthlyDataCollections()
  .where("monthKey", ">=", 20)
  .where("monthKey", "<=", 30)
  .getDailyDataCollections()
  .where("dayKey", ">=", 5)
  .where("monthKey", "<=", 10)
  .get()
  .then(data => {
       process(data);
  });
```

Is there a better way to achieve the requirement than the above solution?

If I was to go with the above solution, what would be the example implementation of the ".getMonthlyDataCollections()" and ".getDailyDataCollections()" from the above firestore query? Meaning, does firestore api provide a kind of "join" like option to actually achieve the above without having to pull all data to the client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> does firestore api provide a kind of "join" like option to actually achieve the above without having to pull all data to the client?

Firestore queries do not provide any sort of SQL-like joins.  Every query can consider only a single collection at a time.  The only exception to this is collection group queries, where you can query among all collections with the same name.

As such, it's common in Firestore (and all NoSQL type databases) to duplicate data among multiple collections in order to satisfy for easier querying.  This is called "denormalization".